# Python break loop and go into loop again

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600, timeout=0)
timeout = time.time() + 60*1

def readresponse():
   while 1:
     try:
        print(ser.readline())
        time.sleep(1)
     except ser.SerialTimeoutException:
        print('Data could not be read')
     if (time.time() > timeout):
        break
     time.sleep(1)

def sendHttpPost():
  ser.write('AT+HTTPACTION=1\r'.encode())
def initialAtCommands():
  ser.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"\r'.encode())
  ser.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"APN\"\r'.encode())
  ser.write('AT+SAPBR=1,1\r'.encode())
  ser.write('AT+HTTPINIT\r'.encode())
  ser.write('AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1\r'.encode())
  ser.write('AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\"URL\"\r'.encode())

 if(ser.isOpen() == False):
    print("Serialport is currently not connected")   
 else:
    print("Serialport successfully connected")
    initialAtCommands()

 while 1:
    sendHttpPost()
    readresponse()
```

The idea is, that sendhttppost is executed and then readresponse for 60 seconds and again sendhttppost. But the code doesn't go into readresponse again.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does your `if` in `readresponse()` in `except`?

Answer (score 2):

Because your `readResponse()` function breaks if and only if it encounters a `serialTimeoutException`. Note that you've put the `break` statement under the `if` block which in turn is inside the `except` block. This means as long as your program doesn't encounter that exception the `while` loop goes on infinitely. If you want the function to return immediately after it executes the `try` block inside `readResponse()`, then just put a `return` statement right after `print(ser.readline())` and put the `time.sleep()` method at the end of the `readResponse()` function. Don't nest it inside the `if` block.

P.S. The `time.sleep(1)` here:

```
if (time.time() > timeout):
        break
        time.sleep(1)
```

is dead code. I think you need to rethink what you wanted to do with the `if` block.

Comment: There were some copy / paste errors in the code. Now it's like it is in my real code.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution myself

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600, timeout=0)
timeout = 60
timeout_start = time.time()

def readresponse():

while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
    try:
        print(ser.readline())
        time.sleep(1)
    except ser.SerialTimeoutException:
        print('Data could not be read')
    time.sleep(1)


def sendHttpPost():
    ser.write('AT+HTTPACTION=1\r'.encode())

def initialAtCommands():
    ser.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"\r'.encode())
    ser.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"APN\"\r'.encode())
    ser.write('AT+SAPBR=1,1\r'.encode())
    ser.write('AT+HTTPINIT\r'.encode())
    ser.write('AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1\r'.encode())
    ser.write('AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"URL\"\r'.encode())

if(ser.isOpen() == False):
    print("Serialport is currently not connected")
else:
    print("Serialport successfully connected")
    initialAtCommands()

while 1:
    sendHttpPost()
    time.sleep(1)
    readresponse()
    timeout_start = time.time()
    time.sleep(1)
```